# Size of particular set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Consider the set

$$B=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3....):x_i\in\{0,1\}$$ $$ \text{and } x_i=0\text{ for }i\geq n \text{ for some }n>0 \}.$$

I must show that $B$ is countably infinite.
Consider the following subset of $B$, defined as

$$B_n=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3...,) \in B:x_i=0\text{ whenever }i\geq n\}$$

Note that as the sequences are in $B$, if $j< n$, $x_j$ can also be 0.

For example, the elements of $B_2$ are

$$(1,0,0,0,\ldots),(0,0,0,0,\ldots).$$

In $B_n$, each $x_j$ for $j<n$ can either be 0 or 1, and so $B_n$ has $2^{n-1}$ elements.

Hence for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$,  $B_n$ is finite.

Observe that $B_1,B_2,B_3....$ is an enumeration of the family, which means that $B_i\neq B_j$ for $i\neq j$ and therefore, we have a countably infinite family. Alternatively, as the sequence $B_1,B_2...$ is indexed by the natural numbers, the family must be countably infinite. Hence, by Cantor's theorem, since

$$\bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}}B_n=B,$$

$B$ must be countably infinite.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: What is $n$ in your first equation?

Comment: Nitpick:  $B$ as written is not well defined as $n$ is not defined.  Better say $B= \{(x_1,x_2, x_3,....)|x_i =0$ or $x_i = 1$ and there exists an $n$ so that $x_i =0$ if $i\ge n\}$

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: Note that $B_i \subset B_{i+1}$.  I guess that doesn't change anything but you have to be careful that a countable union doesn't nesc. mean a countable union of *disjoint* sets.